# How to print messages from MySQL for debugging purposes?

Tags: mysql

I'm more of a MS-SQL / PostgreSQL guy, but I'm working on a MySQL project.  In one of my sprocs (functions) I would like to simply output the value of a variable at runtime for debugging purposes.

With PostgreSQL, this is done using [RAISE NOTICE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html).  This there an equivalent method in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not available for MySQL.

But you can create something similar yourself by storing debugging values in a separate table as [this article](http://gilfster.blogspot.com/2006/03/debugging-stored-procedures-in-mysql.html) describes.

Comment: How would I print a debug message and not have it interfere with my trigger? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344015/mysql-trigger-not-working (look at the edit section)

Comment: @shnozolla [Ask new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead of hijacking an old question, so it can be properly answered.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL procs are in their infancy compared to most modern RDBMS. You'll have to use the poor Man's debugging approach - select var from dual where applicable.