# mysql trigger not working?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to insert a new row conditionally based on an insert on another table...I can't seem to nail the syntax.
Here is what I have thus far:

```
DELIMETER $$
CREATE TRIGGER overPricedCar
    AFTER INSERT ON cars
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN   
        IF (new.sellPrice > '80000' )THEN
        INSERT INTO listings VALUES(new.carName,'GOLD','0',' ');
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMETER ;
```

For some reason I keep getting an error, they syntax seems to be OK, I'm not sure where I may have gone wrong.

**EDIT**

After correcting the typo, the trigger 'works'.

I have added a comment to be output when the trigger happens.
I have tested it, and the output message gets printed to the screen but the trigger does not actually complete the inserts:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER overPricedCar
    BEFORE INSERT ON cars
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN   
        IF (new.sellPrice > '80000' )THEN
        INSERT INTO listings VALUES(new.carName,'GOLD','0',' ');
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "New Gold car!"; // this line throws it off
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Where can I place the messages I want to be printed to the screen when this trigger runs?

Comment: @jcho360 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMETER $$
CREATE TRIGGER overPricedCar
    AFTER INSERT ON cars
    FOR EACH ROW
    B' at line 1

Comment: Here is the same question as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912102/how-can-i-simulate-a-print-statement-in-mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typo:

```
DELIMETER
     ^--- should be an I: DELIMITER
```

Comment: #WTF? how did you see that?!! nice job +1

Comment: Wow! these typos are killing me! I could not find the issue, i'm going to print a huge sign and hang it in front of my desk "CHECK FOR TYPOS" tnx.

Comment: @Marc B When I do an insert that sets off the trigger, no records are entered (neither on 'car' nor on 'listings' table) but the message does get triggered?